# Numerical Methods that find roots like Durand Kerner

Tags: numerical-methods

I need to find n roots for a given polynomial of order n, single root methods like newton and secant wont work in this case, and Durand Kerner doesn't seem to converge nearly as often as I need it to, are there any other stable methods that output multiple roots? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate on the problems with Newton (with deflation). Try Newtons method for $f(z)=p(z)·e^{i\epsilon z}$. How do you determine the initial configuration of root approximations of Durand-Kerner?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem ?

Comment: i use the standard non  unity 0.4 + .9i

Comment: Have you looked into Aberth's method?